# When did the error function get its modern definition?

Tags: terminology, calculus

I am currently writing an essay on the error function and after researching its historical origin, I found out who first defined it: J.W.L. Glaisher. But his definition is different from today's form. His definition: $\int_x^∞e^{-x^2}dx = \operatorname{erf}(x)$ and today: $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-x^2}dx$. I would like to know when they changed it and what the reason was.

Comment: Interesting, and good luck!

Comment: The reason: Presumably, the adjustment is to make $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ increasing, odd, and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\operatorname{erf}(x) = 1$.  Who did it, I don't know.  Some older reference books do not have the $2/\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Why is the error function defined as it is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37889/13130) *AND* [Motivation of the Gaussian Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61480/13130) *AND* the references in [this manuscript](https://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/normal_history.pdf). Maybe also look in [**A History of the Central Limit Theorem. From Classical to Modern Probability Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1461427010) by Fischer (2011) *AND* [**The Life and Times of the Central Limit Theorem**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821848992) by Adams (2009, 2nd edition).

Comment: Glaisher used $\operatorname{erfc}(x)=\int_x^\infty \exp(-t^2)dt$ in 1875: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_London_Mathematical_S/4ofxAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=erfc&pg=PA129&printsec=frontcover p.129, which is what he called $\operatorname{erf)(x)$ in the 1871 papers cited in the Wikipedia article on the error function.

Comment: The 1894 Encyclopedia article on "Tables" shows the variety of usages (with and without the scale factor, with and without the range complementation): https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Encyclopaedia_Britannica/KGlJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=erfc&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover .  "...it has since been found convenient to transpose as above the definitions of Erf and Erfc."

Comment: A. Erdélyi, et al. (eds.), *Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol. II*, New York: McGraw-Hill 1953, p. 147 has $\mathrm{Erf} \  x = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}}  dt$, so the swap between the designations of $\mathrm{Erf}$ and $\mathrm{Erfc}$ would appear to have happened prior to that, while the scale factor $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ would appear to have been added later than that. My copy of A&S (1964) uses the modern form with the scale factor. Presumably the switch in common usage occurred gradually rather than in a single defined event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Harold Jeffreys's  1927 book [Operational Methods in Mathematical Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Operational_Methods_in_Mathematical_Phys/0yI7AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) has a 2-page note titled "On the notation for the error function or probability integral" on pages 94-95, with 9 footnotes, addressing your question. (The link I give has a free pdf download option.) He seems to say that Jeans introduced the $\frac2{\sqrt\pi}$ factor, in his 1921 book *The Dynamical Theory of Gases*.

A partial resolution of the inconsistency of names is to see that where Glaisher, Whittaker and Watson, etc. use $\operatorname{Erf}$ and $\operatorname{Erfc}$ for the unscaled functions, A&S, Wikipedia, DLMF, etc. use $\operatorname{erf}$ and $\operatorname{erfc}$ for the scaled ones.  But Jeffreys uses $\operatorname{Erf}$ for the scaled version, so the inconsistency is not eliminated.

Comment: @njuffa I meant, J&E.  The version at https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=wu.89078198231&view=1up&seq=47&q1=fehlerintegral shows J&E using $\Phi(x)$ to denote the modern $\operatorname{erf}$.  That is, J&E did not use the erf _notation_.  I am sure Jeffries's German was better than mine, and J&E is not at all hard to read.

Comment: @njuffa J&E's $\Phi$ is not the modern $\Phi$ because there is a factor of $\sqrt 2$ applied to the argument.  The one is the indefinite integral of $\exp(-x^2)$ and the other is that of $\exp(-x^2/2)$.